# Azure Data Factory get data from foreach value

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-factory

I've a lookup activity with gets value from a container within a blob.  I've a foreach activity which is connected to the lookup activity

[image]

and under settings it has the value:

```
@activity('LookupMessageType').output.value
```

I've another copy activity which runs within this foreach activity.  It copies data from cosmos DB to Azure Data Lake.
[image]

This is the query in the source dataset:

```
select c.Tag, data.assetTag, data.timestamp, data.jsonVersion, data.messageType, data.speed from c join data in c.data
where (data.speed>  item().speed_Value) AND
(data.timestamp >= '@{formatDateTime(addhours(pipeline().TriggerTime, -1), 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ' )}' 
AND data.timestamp < '@{formatDateTime(pipeline().TriggerTime, 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ' )}')
```

I get an error as I run this pipeline:

```
{
    "errorCode": "2200",
    "message": "Failure happened on 'Source' side. ErrorCode=UserErrorDocumentDBReadError,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=DocumentDb operation failed: Message: {\"errors\":[{\"severity\":\"Error\",\"location\":{\"start\":231,\"end\":235},\"code\":\"SC2005\",\"message\":\"'item' is not a recognized built-in function name.\"}]}\r\nActivityId: *redacted*, documentdb-dotnet-sdk/1.21.1 Host/64-bit MicrosoftWindowsNT/6.2.9200.0.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.DocumentDb,''Type=Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BadRequestException,Message=Message: {\"errors\":[{\"severity\":\"Error\",\"location\":{\"start\":231,\"end\":235},\"code\":\"SC2005\",\"message\":\"'item' is not a recognized built-in function name.\"}]}\r\nActivityId: redacted, documentdb-dotnet-sdk/1.21.1 Host/64-bit MicrosoftWindowsNT/6.2.9200.0,Source=Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client,''Type=System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException,Message=Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A0B00,Source=,'",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "Copy Data1"
}
```

It is saying item is not a built in function name.  I want to use value from the foreach activity to query the source.

Furthermore, here is my dynamic filepath content

```
@concat('test_', item().speed, '.csv')
```

I get the desired dynamic file structure with this expression, if I am using static values in the query like:   `data.speed> 500`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So, I figured out what was wrong with the query:
instead of

`where (data.speed>  item().speed_Value)`

I had to use

```
where (data.speed> @{item().speed_value})
```

Comment: Pretty answer, you could mark it for others' reference.